# Limit of $\frac{1-2\cos(x)+\cos^2(2x)}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus

I tried to find the value of this limit without L'Hopital , but no luck

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-2\cos(x)+\cos^2(2x)}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{1-2\cos(x)+\cos^2(2x)}{x^2}=\frac{4\sin^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2(2x)}{x^2}$$
and since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, your limit equals $1-4=\color{red}{-3}$.

Comment: Sorry, there is mistake in my limit, the last term should be $\cos^2{(2x)}$. I edited it.

Comment: @Leonardo: answer updated accordingly.

Comment: it was easy more than I think. I calculated several times and I did not pay attention to -2. thank you

Comment: @Leonardo: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take the small $x$ expansion for $\cos()$ and apply that.

$$\cos(x) \approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

$$\frac{1-2\cos(x)+\cos^2(2x))}{x^2} \approx \frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-2+x^2+1-2(2x)\right)=-3$$

We don't even have to take a limit in the small expansion to order $x^2$ !

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say "L'Hopital does not work"?  Differentiating the numerator and denominator separately, we get $\frac{2 sin(x)- 4 sin(2x)cos(2x)}{2x}$.  Since both numerator and denominator still go to 0, do it again:  $\frac{2cos(x)- 8cos^2(2x)+ 8sin^2(2x)}{2}$.  Now we can take the limit, as x goes to 0 by evaluating at x= 0:  $\frac{2(1)- 8+ 0}{2}= -\frac{6}{2}= -3$.